# How do I append columns from a list of data frames?

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have the following list of dataframes:

```
lst <- list(
a=data.frame(key=c(1,2,3), val=c(10,20,30)), 
b=data.frame(key=c(1,2,3), val=c(100,200,300)), 
c=data.frame(key=c(1,2,3), val=c(1000,2000,3000)), 
d=data.frame(key=c(1,2), val=c(10000,20000)))
```

How do I create a data.frame as follows? (or similar):

```
  key val.a val.b val.c val.d
1   1    10   100  1000 10000
2   2    20   200  2000 20000
3   3    30   300  3000 NA
```

I tried to do it this way (but FAILED):

```
Browse[2]> Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x, y, by = 'key', all.x = T), lst)
  key val.x val.y val.x val.y
1   1    10   100  1000 10000
2   2    20   200  2000 20000
3   3    30   300  3000 NA
Warning message:
In merge.data.frame(x, y, by = "key", all.x = T) :
  column names ‘val.x’, ‘val.y’ are duplicated in the result
```

> NOTE: I would prefer a base-R solution but am interested in other ways
>   of doing this

Comment: Your "FAILED" attempt looks fine to me, you just need to rename the columns. `names(result)[-1] = paste0("val", names(lst))`

Comment: Alternately you could rename the columns before merging, `for(i in seq_along(lst)) {names(lst[[i]])[2] = paste0(names(list[[i]])[2], names(lst)[i])}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `inner_join` with `reduce` after `renaming` the second column with the corresponding `list` name

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
imap(lst, ~ { nm <- .y
              .x %>% 
                rename_at(vars(val), ~ str_c(., ".", nm))}) %>% 
    reduce(full_join, by = 'key')
#    key val.a val.b val.c val.d
#1   1    10   100  1000 10000
#2   2    20   200  2000 20000
#3   3    30   300  3000 30000
```

---

Or in `base R`, we use `Map` to do the renaming of the column, then as in the OP's post, do the `merge` within `Reduce`

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = 'key', all = TRUE), 
       Map(function(x, y) setNames(x, c('key',
           paste0(names(x)[-1], ".", y))), lst, names(lst)))
#  key val.a val.b val.c val.d
#1   1    10   100  1000 10000
#2   2    20   200  2000 20000
#3   3    30   300  3000 30000
```

Comment: Added `all = T` to the merge because if there is a missing key in one of the data.frames we don't want that whole row to be dropped from the final data.frame

Answer (score 2):

If you are not too fussed about the column names etc looking exactly they way you have it, you can use the following:

```
df_merged = do.call(cbind,lst) %>% 
  select(key = a.key, 2,4,6,8)
```

with output:

```
   key a.val b.val c.val d.val
1     1    10   100  1000 10000
2     2    20   200  2000 20000
3     3    30   300  3000 30000
```

Comment: will this handle the case if I have a missing key value in one of the data.frames? i.e. suppose all data.frames in a list have a key = 2 but 1 of the data.frames doesn't. Will this result in an NA in that column or will the results just get messed up?

Comment: Just checked it, by removing key = 3 from item "d", you get an error about differing lengths

Answer (score 1):

If `lst` is the starting list, then:

```
library(dplyr);

#binding columns and then dropping the extra columns
df <- bind_cols(lst$a, lst$b, lst$c, lst$d)  %>% 
      select(-c(3,5,7)); 

#Use whatever name you want for the columns:
colnames(df)[c(2:5)] <- c("valLis1","valLis2","valLis3","valLis4");

df;
  key valLis1 valLis2 valLis3 valLis4
1   1      10     100    1000   10000
2   2      20     200    2000   20000
3   3      30     300    3000   30000
```

Comment: I think this will have a problem if the number of rows differ in some data.frame

Answer (score 1):

A more robust solution in `Base R` with edge cases shown. This solution searches for every unique key across the entire list and fills the tables with `NA`'s where appropriate.

```
lst <- list(
  a=data.frame(key=c(1,2,3), val=c(10,20,30)), 
  b=data.frame(key=c(1,2,3), val=c(100,200,300)), 
  c=data.frame(key=c(1,2,3,4), val=c(1000,2000,3000,4000)), 
  d=data.frame(key=c(1,3), val=c(10000,30000)))

df <- data.frame(key = unique(unlist(sapply(1:length(lst), function(x) lst[[x]]$key))))
df[2:(length(lst)+1)] <- NA

for(i in 1:length(lst)){df[,(i+1)][sapply(lst[[i]]$key,match,df$key)] <- lst[[i]]$val}

colnames(df)[2:NCOL(df)] <- paste0("val.",names(lst))
```

Output

```
> df
  key val.a val.b val.c val.d
1   1    10   100  1000 10000
2   2    20   200  2000    NA
3   3    30   300  3000 30000
4   4    NA    NA  4000    NA
```

---

> First attempt in `Base R`
>
> ```
>   df <- data.frame(key = c(1,2,3))
>   df <- cbind(df,sapply(1:length(lst), function(x) lst[[x]]$val))
> ```
>
> and to auto name your columns
>
> ```
> colnames(df)[2:NCOL(df)] <- paste0("val.",names(lst))
> ```

Comment: I think this will have a problem if the number of rows differ in some data.frame

Comment: @Denis I wrote a much more robust solution for you still in Base-R